# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, out-of-memory

I have trying to export my data into excel sheet it contains nearly 70000 rows.
I am getting the below error:

> Exception in thread "http-bio-8765-exec-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
>   Java heap space
>         at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1700)
>         at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1303)
>         at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1190)

Below is the code used to write Excel:

```
public String getXLSWriter(ResultSet rs, String file_name)
    {
        String filepath="";
        try {
            //String filename=file_name.replace('/','_');
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(file_name);

            XSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((int) 0);
             filepath=prop.getProperty("file_store_path")+file_name+timeStamp+".xlsx";

            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
            rowhead.createCell((int) 0).setCellValue("ID");
            rowhead.createCell((int) 1).setCellValue("firstName");
            rowhead.createCell((int) 2).setCellValue("LastName");

            int i = 1;
            while (rs.next()){
                XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((int) i);

                row.createCell((int) 0).setCellValue(rs.getString("id")); 
                row.createCell((int) 1).setCellValue(rs.getString("first_name") );
                row.createCell((int) 2).setCellValue(rs.getString("last_name"));


                i++;
            }

            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("XLS done!!"); 
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Below is the code i used for downloading the Excel:

```
public void getDownloaded(String filepath,HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        try {
            File file=new File(filepath);
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="+file.getName());
            FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(file);
            ServletOutputStream out=response.getOutputStream();
            byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
            //copy binary content to output stream
            int length;
            while((length=in.read(outputByte, 0, 4096)) != -1){
                out.write(outputByte, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

Comment: You are running out of memory. Please include full stacktrace in the question

Comment: how big is your excel file? how big is your VM Memory?

Comment: Why is full stack trace relevant? Out of memory is out of memory.

Comment: @BalusC because we don't know what method caused it. Is it when generating excel file? Or when attaching to response?

Comment: @ADS: the 1st line of the stack trace already answered that. Even then, final solution would still be the same: just give more memory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't read all the data at once or use -Xmx option when you start java to increase the max memory.
Check for a memory leak and import this data in a database to save local memory.